# Why are my lat/long coordinates different from my utm coordinates?

Tags: r

I have a set of tracking data that I'm attempting to convert from utm to lat/long. The issue is that when I plot the utm coordinates and converted lat/long coordinates, the converted coordinates appear to be consistently off by roughly 800 feet. I need to extract environmental data associated with each point, so ideally they should be as close as possible.

Here's my code so far for converting utm to lat/long coorinates using a sample of my data. In case it's relevant, my study site is located in Arizona near Phoenix.

```
library(terra)

#Creating utm data
x<-c(421131,421050)
y<-c(3732608,3732702)

points <- cbind(x, y) #creating a matrix of utm coordinates
v <- vect(points, crs="+proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=NAD27 +units=m +no_defs") #applying the right crs for the utm coordinates
v

#tranforming the CRS of the object to a lat/long format
y <- project(v, "+proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0") #pplying the right crs for lat/long coordinates
y
#Extracting the coordinates
lonlat <- geom(y)[, c("x", "y")]
lonlat<-as.data.frame(lonlat) #creating a dataframe of lat/long coordinates
```

This results in lat/long coordinates that, when plotted on the GPS Geoplaner website, are close to but still about 800 ft off from my original points.

not sure if it'll work, but I'll try adding a screenshot of the plotted coordinates, with points A and C being the original UTM locations, and B and D being the new incorrect lat/long locations. They're pretty close, just shifted north a few hundred feet. Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks!

[image: image of plotted coordinates]

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think that your coordinates are relative to the NAD27 datum? That is possible, but it would be odd. And a web map is not likely to use that datum. Also, this is weird: `"+proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs +ellps=GRS80"` as you are using NAD27 (from 1927) but an ellips defined in 1980.

With your approach I see

```
library(terra)
x <- c(421131, 421050)
y <- c(3732608, 3732702)
v <- vect(cbind(x, y), crs="+proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=NAD27 +units=m") 
p <- project(v, "+proj=longlat +datum=NAD27") 
crds(p)
#             x        y
#[1,] -111.8514 33.73231
#[2,] -111.8522 33.73316
```

But things change if you do

```
v <- vect(cbind(x, y), crs="+proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=NAD83 +units=m")
p2 <- project(v, "+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83") 
crds(p2)
#             x        y
#[1,] -111.8514 33.73057
#[2,] -111.8522 33.73141
```

Is that better? If not, can you edit your question and tell us what the correct lon/lat coordinates are. E.g. look them up by right clicking on the locations in Google Maps.

Comment: Thanks so much, that looks much better now!